# type object 'Video' has no attribute 'video_file' django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to display a mp4 on my site and i'm putting it in the context but for some reason when I visit the page I get this: 'type object 'Video' has no attribute 'video_file'

Have tried a few things but none of them worked.

**Views.py**

```py
def movie(request, movie_id):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Video, title=movie_id) # This only gets the movie name
    mp4 = Video.video_file.url
    context = {'video': movie, 'mp4':mp4}
    return render(request, template_name=f'uploadvideos/movie.html', context=context)
```

**models.py**

```py
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    video_file = models.FileField(name="Upload a mp4 file",
                                  upload_to=f"uploadvideos/video",
                                  validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['mp4'])],
                                  blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**movie.html**

```html
    <h1 class="movietitle">{{ video }}</h1>
    <div class="videoDetails">
        <video width="700" height="430" controls>
            <source src="{{ mp4 }}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
```

I expected the video to be shown but instead I got this error: 
'type object 'Video' has no attribute 'video_file'

Comment: Did you mean `movie.video_file`?

Comment: that doesn't work for some reason as it shows 0 output even when I try to just make a simple h1 and have movie.video_file.name, I get no output on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The `Video` refers to the `Video` *class*, since the `Video` *instance* here is named `movie`, you thus should use:

```
def movie(request, movie_id):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Video, title=movie_id)
    context = {'video': movie, 'mp4': movie.video_file.url }
    return render(request, 'uploadvideos/movie.html', context)
```

Your assumption:

> ```
> # This only gets the movie name
> ```

is wrong. This will load a `Video` object. If you *render* this object, it will call the `str(..)` function on that object, and that will indeed return the title, but that does *not* mean that `movie` itself is a string.

Comment: I still get the same error as previously which is AttributeError at /video/test1/

'Video' object has no attribute 'video_file'

Comment: @Lol123abc: I made a typo, it is `video_file`, not `vide_file`.

Comment: Yeah I know I changed accordingly it still gives me the same error unfortunately.